# postman params not sent to web api controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have this web api controller:

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        private mw2devnew15Entities db = new mw2devnew15Entities();

        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public string Post()
        {
            string authenticationToken = "";
            return authenticationToken;
        }


        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(JObject data)
        {
            dynamic json = data;

            LoginForm loginF = new LoginForm();
            loginF.username = json.username;
            loginF.password = json.password;

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
```

I'm able to post correctly with this ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:5832/api/Login",
            data: JSON.stringify({ username: 'joep11aul1234', password: '1212213' }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

But when I'm trying to use Postman to place POST call, the JObject is null.

[image]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Postman you're not reproducing the same request as your JavaScript code since you posting the parameters in the query string. What you shoud do instead is something like this:

Add a content type header with the value of `application/json`:

[image]

and for your request body select `raw` and then add your JSON:

[image]

this will send the following request same as your JavaScript code:

```
POST /api/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5832
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4bf25ded-7548-77f9-3389-fa16a5d50087

{ "username": "joep11aul1234", "password": "1212213" }
```

Comment: @Laziale Glad I could help. Happy coding :)